# Can I declare 2 variables from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables, variable-assignment

I currently have this in my code:

```
var user = this.value.split("@")[0];
var domain = this.value.split("@")[1];
```

I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
var user, domain = this.value.split("@");
```

(But of course this creates an empty variable "user", and assigns "domain" to the array returned by .split())

---

I managed to do this in PHP like so:

```
list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $_POST['user']);
```

Was wondering if there is a JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: In `ES5` you can not do that, in `ES6` you can (http://goo.gl/Rwsi0e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 will add [*destructuring assignments*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment), which lets you do very nearly what you've written:

```
// Will be valid in ES6
var [user, domain] = this.value.split("@");
```

...but you can't do it (in most engines) today. Instead, you need an intermediate variable:

```
var parts = this.value.split("@");
var user = parts[0];
var domain = parts[1];
```

...or just duplicate the `split` as you've done.

Here's a live example that works in recent versions of Firefox, which already have destructuring assignments:

```js
// Requires that destructuring assignments work on your browser;
// recent Firefox has them
var value = "coolness@example.com";
var [user, domain] = value.split("@");
snippet.log("user = " + user);
snippet.log("domain = " + domain);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: a temporary variable is probably a fraction of a millisecond faster I guess, since split() is only run once.

Comment: @TRGWII: Exactly. Or (again) just repeat the `split`, as you've done, if you don't need that fraction of a millisecond.